# React Native iOS standalone crashing on react.ShadowQueue

Tags: ios, react-native

Dev specs:

- Expo SDK Version: 3.0.10
- Workflow: ExpoKit
- React Native: 0.59.8
- Platforms: iOS/Android

Hi! I created an app for iOS and Android. The Android version works great, the iOS not so much. The iOS keeps crashing right after launching it. Below is the crash log, and I have no idea how to debug it :frowning:.

It is crashing in the simulator as well as in the physical device. I thought it was perhaps the Push Notification, because it doesn’t work on the simulator, I commented it out and still keeps crashing. What I guess it might be is access to device storage. The app, right after the splash screen, shows a ActivityIndicator while looking into the device storage for a saved user token, and a few seconds after the ActivityIndicator shows it crashes. I know it won’t find a user token, so then if should display the login screen, but the app crashes before this. I am using expo-secure-store for local storage.

I have two full logs on Google Drive:

[Error-log-1.txt](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ndNIwP0_QhuyMD-_h407BgGodFV9B1vC)

[Error-log-2.txt](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1OUVNKdeX5P7RssOFIvcWibWhrgiu96t5)

Here is the short version:

```
Thread 3 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.facebook.react.ShadowQueue
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000010cc9fdda __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000010ccd7797 pthread_kill + 90
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000010ca3188f abort + 127
3   com.myapp.app           0x00000001026ca4db YGVLog(YGConfig*, YGNode*, YGLogLevel, char const*, __va_list_tag*) + 68
4   com.myapp.app           0x00000001026c5d09 YGLog + 155
5   com.myapp.app           0x00000001026cab5a YGBaseline(YGNode*) + 95
6   com.myapp.app           0x00000001026cabee YGBaseline(YGNode*) + 243
7   com.myapp.app           0x00000001026cabee YGBaseline(YGNode*) + 243
8   com.myapp.app           0x00000001026cabee YGBaseline(YGNode*) + 243
9   com.myapp.app           0x00000001026c794a YGNodelayoutImpl(YGNode*, float, float, YGDirection, YGMeasureMode, YGMeasureMode, float, float, bool, YGConfig*, YGMarkerLayoutData&) + 7203
10  com.myapp.app           0x00000001026c5a56 YGLayoutNodeInternal(YGNode*, float, float, YGDirection, YGMeasureMode, YGMeasureMode, float, float, bool, char const*, YGConfig*, YGMarkerLayoutData&) + 1288
11  com.myapp.app           0x00000001026cb641 YGNodeComputeFlexBasisForChild(YGNode*, YGNode*, float, YGMeasureMode, float, float, float, YGMeasureMode, YGDirection, YGConfig*, YGMarkerLayoutData&) + 1679
12  com.myapp.app           0x00000001026c6943 YGNodelayoutImpl(YGNode*, float, float, YGDirection, YGMeasureMode, YGMeasureMode, float, float, bool, YGConfig*, YGMarkerLayoutData&) + 3100
13  com.myapp.app           0x00000001026c5a56 YGLayoutNodeInternal(YGNode*, float, float, YGDirection, YGMeasureMode, YGMeasureMode, float, float, bool, char const*, YGConfig*, YGMarkerLayoutData&) + 1288
14  com.myapp.app           0x00000001026cb641 YGNodeComputeFlexBasisForChild(YGNode*, YGNode*, float, YGMeasureMode, float, float, float, YGMeasureMode, YGDirection, YGConfig*, YGMarkerLayoutData&) + 1679
15  com.myapp.app           0x00000001026c6943 YGNodelayoutImpl(YGNode*, float, float, YGDirection, YGMeasureMode, YGMeasureMode, float, float, bool, YGConfig*, YGMarkerLayoutData&) + 3100
16  com.myapp.app           0x00000001026c5a56 YGLayoutNodeInternal(YGNode*, float, float, YGDirection, YGMeasureMode, YGMeasureMode, float, float, bool, char const*, YGConfig*, YGMarkerLayoutData&) + 1288
17  com.myapp.app           0x00000001026cb641 YGNodeComputeFlexBasisForChild(YGNode*, YGNode*, float, YGMeasureMode, float, float, float, YGMeasureMode, YGDirection, YGConfig*, YGMarkerLayoutData&) + 1679
18  com.myapp.app           0x00000001026c6943 YGNodelayoutImpl(YGNode*, float, float, YGDirection, YGMeasureMode, YGMeasureMode, float, float, bool, YGConfig*, YGMarkerLayoutData&) + 3100
19  com.myapp.app           0x00000001026c5a56 YGLayoutNodeInternal(YGNode*, float, float, YGDirection, YGMeasureMode, YGMeasureMode, float, float, bool, char const*, YGConfig*, YGMarkerLayoutData&) + 1288
20  com.myapp.app           0x00000001026cb641 YGNodeComputeFlexBasisForChild(YGNode*, YGNode*, float, YGMeasureMode, float, float, float, YGMeasureMode, YGDirection, YGConfig*, YGMarkerLayoutData&) + 1679
21  com.myapp.app           0x00000001026c6943 YGNodelayoutImpl(YGNode*, float, float, YGDirection, YGMeasureMode, YGMeasureMode, float, float, bool, YGConfig*, YGMarkerLayoutData&) + 3100
22  com.myapp.app           0x00000001026c5a56 YGLayoutNodeInternal(YGNode*, float, float, YGDirection, YGMeasureMode, YGMeasureMode, float, float, bool, char const*, YGConfig*, YGMarkerLayoutData&) + 1288
23  com.myapp.app           0x00000001026cb641 YGNodeComputeFlexBasisForChild(YGNode*, YGNode*, float, YGMeasureMode, float, float, float, YGMeasureMode, YGDirection, YGConfig*, YGMarkerLayoutData&) + 1679
24  com.myapp.app           0x00000001026c6943 YGNodelayoutImpl(YGNode*, float, float, YGDirection, YGMeasureMode, YGMeasureMode, float, float, bool, YGConfig*, YGMarkerLayoutData&) + 3100
25  com.myapp.app           0x00000001026c5a56 YGLayoutNodeInternal(YGNode*, float, float, YGDirection, YGMeasureMode, YGMeasureMode, float, float, bool, char const*, YGConfig*, YGMarkerLayoutData&) + 1288
26  com.myapp.app           0x00000001026cb641 YGNodeComputeFlexBasisForChild(YGNode*, YGNode*, float, YGMeasureMode, float, float, float, YGMeasureMode, YGDirection, YGConfig*, YGMarkerLayoutData&) + 1679
27  com.myapp.app           0x00000001026c6943 YGNodelayoutImpl(YGNode*, float, float, YGDirection, YGMeasureMode, YGMeasureMode, float, float, bool, YGConfig*, YGMarkerLayoutData&) + 3100
28  com.myapp.app           0x00000001026c5a56 YGLayoutNodeInternal(YGNode*, float, float, YGDirection, YGMeasureMode, YGMeasureMode, float, float, bool, char const*, YGConfig*, YGMarkerLayoutData&) + 1288
29  com.myapp.app           0x00000001026cb641 YGNodeComputeFlexBasisForChild(YGNode*, YGNode*, float, YGMeasureMode, float, float, float, YGMeasureMode, YGDirection, YGConfig*, YGMarkerLayoutData&) + 1679
30  com.myapp.app           0x00000001026c6943 YGNodelayoutImpl(YGNode*, float, float, YGDirection, YGMeasureMode, YGMeasureMode, float, float, bool, YGConfig*, YGMarkerLayoutData&) + 3100
31  com.myapp.app           0x00000001026c5a56 YGLayoutNodeInternal(YGNode*, float, float, YGDirection, YGMeasureMode, YGMeasureMode, float, float, bool, char const*, YGConfig*, YGMarkerLayoutData&) + 1288
32  com.myapp.app           0x00000001026c7d68 YGNodelayoutImpl(YGNode*, float, float, YGDirection, YGMeasureMode, YGMeasureMode, float, float, bool, YGConfig*, YGMarkerLayoutData&) + 8257
33  com.myapp.app           0x00000001026c5a56 YGLayoutNodeInternal(YGNode*, float, float, YGDirection, YGMeasureMode, YGMeasureMode, float, float, bool, char const*, YGConfig*, YGMarkerLayoutData&) + 1288
34  com.myapp.app           0x00000001026c7d68 YGNodelayoutImpl(YGNode*, float, float, YGDirection, YGMeasureMode, YGMeasureMode, float, float, bool, YGConfig*, YGMarkerLayoutData&) + 8257
35  com.myapp.app           0x00000001026c5a56 YGLayoutNodeInternal(YGNode*, float, float, YGDirection, YGMeasureMode, YGMeasureMode, float, float, bool, char const*, YGConfig*, YGMarkerLayoutData&) + 1288
36  com.myapp.app           0x00000001026c7d68 YGNodelayoutImpl(YGNode*, float, float, YGDirection, YGMeasureMode, YGMeasureMode, float, float, bool, YGConfig*, YGMarkerLayoutData&) + 8257
37  com.myapp.app           0x00000001026c5a56 YGLayoutNodeInternal(YGNode*, float, float, YGDirection, YGMeasureMode, YGMeasureMode, float, float, bool, char const*, YGConfig*, YGMarkerLayoutData&) + 1288
38  com.myapp.app           0x00000001026c9274 YGNodelayoutImpl(YGNode*, float, float, YGDirection, YGMeasureMode, YGMeasureMode, float, float, bool, YGConfig*, YGMarkerLayoutData&) + 13645
39  com.myapp.app           0x00000001026c5a56 YGLayoutNodeInternal(YGNode*, float, float, YGDirection, YGMeasureMode, YGMeasureMode, float, float, bool, char const*, YGConfig*, YGMarkerLayoutData&) + 1288
40  com.myapp.app           0x00000001026c7d68 YGNodelayoutImpl(YGNode*, float, float, YGDirection, YGMeasureMode, YGMeasureMode, float, float, bool, YGConfig*, YGMarkerLayoutData&) + 8257
41  com.myapp.app           0x00000001026c5a56 YGLayoutNodeInternal(YGNode*, float, float, YGDirection, YGMeasureMode, YGMeasureMode, float, float, bool, char const*, YGConfig*, YGMarkerLayoutData&) + 1288
42  com.myapp.app           0x00000001026c7d68 YGNodelayoutImpl(YGNode*, float, float, YGDirection, YGMeasureMode, YGMeasureMode, float, float, bool, YGConfig*, YGMarkerLayoutData&) + 8257
43  com.myapp.app           0x00000001026c5a56 YGLayoutNodeInternal(YGNode*, float, float, YGDirection, YGMeasureMode, YGMeasureMode, float, float, bool, char const*, YGConfig*, YGMarkerLayoutData&) + 1288
44  com.myapp.app           0x00000001026c7d68 YGNodelayoutImpl(YGNode*, float, float, YGDirection, YGMeasureMode, YGMeasureMode, float, float, bool, YGConfig*, YGMarkerLayoutData&) + 8257
45  com.myapp.app           0x00000001026c5a56 YGLayoutNodeInternal(YGNode*, float, float, YGDirection, YGMeasureMode, YGMeasureMode, float, float, bool, char const*, YGConfig*, YGMarkerLayoutData&) + 1288
46  com.myapp.app           0x00000001026c7d68 YGNodelayoutImpl(YGNode*, float, float, YGDirection, YGMeasureMode, YGMeasureMode, float, float, bool, YGConfig*, YGMarkerLayoutData&) + 8257
47  com.myapp.app           0x00000001026c5a56 YGLayoutNodeInternal(YGNode*, float, float, YGDirection, YGMeasureMode, YGMeasureMode, float, float, bool, char const*, YGConfig*, YGMarkerLayoutData&) + 1288
48  com.myapp.app           0x00000001026c7d68 YGNodelayoutImpl(YGNode*, float, float, YGDirection, YGMeasureMode, YGMeasureMode, float, float, bool, YGConfig*, YGMarkerLayoutData&) + 8257
49  com.myapp.app           0x00000001026c5a56 YGLayoutNodeInternal(YGNode*, float, float, YGDirection, YGMeasureMode, YGMeasureMode, float, float, bool, char const*, YGConfig*, YGMarkerLayoutData&) + 1288
50  com.myapp.app           0x00000001026c7d68 YGNodelayoutImpl(YGNode*, float, float, YGDirection, YGMeasureMode, YGMeasureMode, float, float, bool, YGConfig*, YGMarkerLayoutData&) + 8257
51  com.myapp.app           0x00000001026c5a56 YGLayoutNodeInternal(YGNode*, float, float, YGDirection, YGMeasureMode, YGMeasureMode, float, float, bool, char const*, YGConfig*, YGMarkerLayoutData&) + 1288
52  com.myapp.app           0x00000001026c9d96 YGNodeCalculateLayout + 846
53  com.myapp.app           0x000000010264a2c3 -[RCTShadowView layoutWithMinimumSize:maximumSize:layoutDirection:layoutContext:] + 217
54  com.myapp.app           0x000000010263e10e -[RCTRootShadowView layoutWithAffectedShadowViews:] + 185
55  com.myapp.app           0x0000000102666163 -[RCTUIManager uiBlockWithLayoutUpdateForRootView:] + 113
56  com.myapp.app           0x000000010266adcd -[RCTUIManager _layoutAndMount] + 380
57  com.myapp.app           0x00000001025e1976 __32-[RCTCxxBridge batchDidComplete]_block_invoke + 52
58  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000010c91f585 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
59  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000010c940792 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
60  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000010c926237 _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 1022
61  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000010c92698f _dispatch_queue_invoke + 1053
62  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000010c928899 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 813
63  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000010c92850d _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 113
64  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000010ccd4746 _pthread_wqthread + 1299
65  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000010ccd4221 start_wqthread + 13
```

Any suggestion is very welcome, I have no idea where to go from here.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you use `pod install` ?

Comment: No, I didn't. I basically deployed it to Expo.io, download then .ipa file and send it to the device via xcrun command. Other than the simulator, Xcode wasn't used. Did I miss something?

Comment: Do you want to make the Expo a stand-alone app and run it on Xcode?

Comment: Why deploy the Expo, create a .ipa file, and move it to the device?

Comment: To be honest, that's what I thought I should do. It's my first time doing anything with Xcode, I've only worked with Android dev to this point, and now RN. The app was developed on a Ubuntu machine and I have been using VirtualBox to run Xcode for debugging. Getting the ipa file from Expo.io on the virtual machine is the easiest way I found to bridge the file from Ubuntu to MacOS. What should I do from here? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have used the Expo to do the project. And the execution command would have been `expo start` OR `expo start -ios or -android`.

And you would have run `expo eject` to use the React native library.

And If you want to run iOS's project,

- Make sure you have the latest `Xcode`.
- If you don't have it already, install `CocoaPods`, which is a native
  dependency manager for `iOS`.
- Run `pod install` from your project's `ios` directory.

---

1. And Run `expo start` from the project directory.
2. Open your project's `xcworkspace` file in `Xcode`.
3. Use `Xcode` to build, install and run the project on your test
   device or simulator. (this will happen by default if you click the
   big "Play" button in `Xcode`.)

Comment: Thank you. These instructions are for debugging purposes only? I created the project using `expo start`, but I didn't eject from it on the hope of not having to deal with Xcode and Objective-C, as I didn't for Android. I thought the whole purpose of Expo was to create native apps using JS for both platforms, no?

Comment: Yes,  @ColdTuna Expansion is a tool that supports React-native. I thought you had ejected because the word "standalone".  If you have created an Expo project through the 'expo init your project' command, you can run iOS android the same through the command 'expo start'.

Comment: Ok, sorry for misleading you. As a noob to all of this I often confuse myself with Expo, React Native, eject and so on. So you think I should eject and debug it thru Xcode?

Comment: For debugging, you can check the values in the console log. If not, refer to this document.  https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/debugging/

Comment: Yes mate, your answers have been of much help, thank you. Through this process I have been getting more familiar with the workflow of RN/Expo. I just don't know if it will solve my `react.ShadowQueue' crash. The debugging reference you gave me is what I have been doing with Android app; so what I am thinking now is to do the same for iOS, run it thru Expo and see if I get more details on the error I am receiving. Hopefully this will shine some light on this; my client is on my ass because I can't deliver the iOS yet, very frustrating. I'll get back to you soon. Thanks for all the help so far!

Comment: Thru the process you suggested I was able to debug it meticulously and found that the prop `containerStyle` from the package `react-native-material-textfield` is causing the app to crash. I don't know why yet tho, it is only applying a style `{flex:7}`, but I am getting close to the root of the problem. Thank for all your help.

Comment: @ColdTuna  Experience a lot about React-native and share your knowledge.